# Flexbox styling some callout text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to style some callout text using Flexbox.

Hopefully, the following words can describe the visual intent.

I have a mobile layout which is going to be a blog post.

The typical text is just a standard style.

For certain portions of text (perhaps an important paragraph) I want to style this differently -- I am calling this style "callout"

I want this style to have a thin blue vertical line (about 10px) - flush with the left hand side.

Then to the right of this thin blue line, I want the callout text which be in a slightly different style.

The vertical height of the blue line would be equal to the height of the accompanying callout text.

I have an example of my best effort see codepen link (which looks horrible). It contains a few comments in the example, which hopefully makes my intent clear.

https://codepen.io/snowman8003/pen/vPrEzJ

The following is a copy of the relevant CSS flex style:

```
div .call-out {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: stretch;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content:space-evenly;
}

div .call-out-bar {
flex: 1;
width: 10px;
background: blue;
}

div .call-out-text {
flex: 1;
width: 100%;
}
```

The image below. Hopefully makes things clear.

[image: This is an image of what I am basically trying to achieve:]

Thanks for any input,

Mark

Comment: Your two `flex: 1` rules are both missing their colon. Also, what is the desired layout?  I assume the text shouldn't overlap, but you're already pretty tight for horizontal space there. Do you want some of it to drop to the next line? Or add a scrollbar? Or do you want the call-out to sit on top of text (with a higher `z-index`)? A screenshot of the desired layout may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @ObsidianAge.  Hopefully, the image above makes things clear.

Comment: It looks like you can achieve that using only CSS (a border-left and a padding-left) Any reason to use that flex hack?. And I'd recommend you to use the "EM" tag uses to emphazise parts of the text, it will be semantically better https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/em

Comment: @arieljuod In this case semantically correct element would be blockquote: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote

Comment: @joshas, the OP never mentioned it being a quote, for his description I understand he wants to emphasize some part of the text. I can be a quote though, only the OP did not specify that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Yes @arieljuod I understand your point regarding using vanilla CSS.   I am fairly new to CSS and over the last few weeks, I have really to tried hard to understand Flexbox  but "when your a hammer, everything seems like a nail."

Comment: @markthekoala your idea of using flex is also vanilla CSS, what I meant is that you have empty DIV elements just to do styling things like a blue line. It's faster for the browser to calculate a padding and border-left than using a flex box and move elements around, and the right TAG can help people with accessibility requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding-left` should do the trick!

EDIT:
As @arieljuod mentioned, `<em>` could be used as well. This way the 2 `<div>`'s are no longer needed.

```
.call-out-text {
  flex 1;
  width: 100%;

  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}

// EDIT
em {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```css
html, body {
 /*  https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html# */
/* light: 300; regular: 400; medium: 500*/

  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: normal;

/*  this sets 1rem = 16px*/
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/*  border:1px solid rgba(250,0,0,1);*/
}

p {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

div .call-out {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  
}

em {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}

.call-out-text {
  flex 1;
  width: 100%;
  
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FlexBox Nav</title>

  <!-- light: 300; regular: 400; medium: 500 -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="wrap">
  <article>
    <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur, beatae?</p>

    
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. nulla, illum ea consectetur!</p>

    <!-- EDIT -->
    <em>Qwerty!</em>
    
    <!-- Original option -->
    <div class="call-out">
      <div class="call-out-text">
        <p><i>This is a callout bar. It displays something important or unusual that should provide the user with some extra information</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>Now we are back to normal text...</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can achieve that using only CSS (a border-left and a padding-left) Any reason to use that flex hack?. And I'd recommend you to use the "EM" tag used to emphazise parts of the text, it will be semantically better.

```
<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. nulla, illum ea consectetur!</p>

<p><em>This is a callout bar. It displays something important or unusual that should provide the user with some extra information</em></p>

<p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. nulla, illum ea consectetur!</p>
```

And then just padding and border

```
p em {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 10px solid blue;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em